# When to use {$1, x, x^2,\dots$}, or the Gram-Schmidt orthonormal version of it {$1/\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3/2}x, \sqrt{45/8}(x^2-1/3),\dots$}

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

In considering a linear transformation $T$ on a complex vector space, what determines whether one can/should use the standard basis:

{$1, x, x^2,\dots$}, or the Gram-Schmidt, orthonormal version of it, {$1/\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3/2}x, \sqrt{45/8}(x^2-1/3),\dots$}.

In particular, when constructing a matrix representation of $T$, or, e.g., calculating the eigenvalues, singular values of $T$; when $T$ maps $p(x)$ to some function of $p$ involving derivatives, etc. Here $p(x)\in \mathcal P_n(\mathbb{C})$ and $n$ is a fixed positive integer.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computationally it should be obvious that the standard basis is far easier to use than the orthonormal one. In general, unless your argument requires orthonormality, I would strongly encourage using the standard basis. There's really minimal reason to use the orthonormal basis in the context that you're talking about, and the fact that (with respect to the standard basis) the differential operator has a particular nice form might come in handy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering, as for this question I had asked, unless I made a dopy error, I got different values of the singular values using the standard basis. In the latter case I got {$0,1,6$}. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2196746/find-the-singular-values-of-t-px-mapsto-xpx2x2px. With regards,

Comment: @Andrew That shouldn't occur, once you take into account the change of basis. If you did a computation relative to basis $A$ and then wrote the answer in basis $B$, then you will get the same thing as if you rewrote the problem to be in basis $B$ and did the computation there. Actually translating the problem into basis $B$ completely is something that people frequently mess up, so that's the first place I would look for the issue.